# Shared folder for all sites (/usr/share/) Apache

Tags: apache, directory, share

i need share a folder for all my sites hosted in the same apache.

Example:

http://domain1.com/administration/

http://domain2.com/administration/

http://domain3.com/administration/

All three domains will be acces to the same folder "administration"

I think if i create the folder in /USR/SHARE/ will be works... but not... :(

any help? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Imagine that your site is under /var/www/site1 (site.domain.com) and your share folder is under /var/www/share

If you would like to have share as just a subdirectory accessible from site.domain.com/share all you will need to do its to create a symlink from /var/www/share to /var/www/site1/share, repeat this for site2 etc..

```
ln -s /var/www/share /var/www/site/share
```

Comment: Simply mark it as the correct answer using the tick :)